# Using PHP variable in Javascript/Jquery Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am creating an investment calculator that takes user input from six pages and stores them in PHP $_SESSION variables. On the final page i take the $_SESSION variables form PHP and JSON.parse them to Javascript like so:

```
var cash = parseInt(JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($cash_flow); ?>'));
```

I then run the variables through a formula to find a score like so:

```
function SCORE( cash, comp, num_months) {
var total1 = (cash - comp )/( num_months*12);
var total2 = total1/2.5;
var total3 = total2*100;

var dvTotal = total3;

return dvTotal;

}
```

I then use JQuery to output the score to the DOM.

I then have a section with a display of each of the users original input with a + and - next to them allowing the user to update their original input.

```
$('#cashMinusBtn').click(function(){
$('#cashFlowOutput').html(cash-=1000);
var newCash = $('#cashFlowOutput').html();
SCORE( newCash );
$('#dvTestOut').html(scoreTotal);
```

Here is the HTML used to output the user data:

```
div class="container-fluid pro-table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 tooltip-row">
      <h4>Increase or Decrease value of initial entry to see how your dv<strong>SCORE</strong> would be effected:</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row tooltip-display">
    <div class="col-md-2 outputBox">
        <p>Cash Flow</p><br>
        <p id="cashFlowOutput"></p><br>
        <button class="table-button" id="cashMinusBtn">-</button><button class="table-button" id="cashPlusBtn">+</button>


    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 outputBox">

        <p>Purchase Price</p><br>
         <p id="purchaseOutput"></p><br>
         <button class="table-button" id="purchaseMinusBtn">-</button><button class="table-button" id="purchasePlusBtn">+</button>


    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 outputBox">

        <p>Down Payment</p><br>
        <p id="downOutput"></p><br>
        <button class="table-button" id="downMinusBtn">-</button><button class="table-button" id="downPlusBtn">+</button>


    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 outputBox">

        <p>Interest Rate</p><br>
        <p id="interestOutput"></p><br>
        <button class="table-button" id="interestMinusBtn">-</button><button class="table-button" id="interestPlusBtn">+</button>


    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 outputBox">


        <p>Months Financed</p><br>
        <p id="monthsOutput"></p><br>
        <button class="table-button" id="monthsMinusBtn">-</button><button class="table-button" id="monthsPlusBtn">+</button>


  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 outputBox">

      <p>Compensation</p><br>
      <p id="compOutput"></p><br>
      <button class="table-button" id="compMinusBtn">-</button><button class="table-button" id="compPlusBtn">+</button>


  </div>
```

I would like to grab the new data updated by the user via + or -, send it through the formula, and update the score displayed.

I have no problem grabbing the updated data with `var newCash = $('#cashFlowOutput').html();`

But i'm having trouble pushing the newCash back through the formula and updating the score.

I'll include the repo for this material, i understand that some of the work has vulnerabilities but it is still and work in progress on a local server: https://github.com/DLzer/YarmouthApp/blob/master/finalPage.php

This is my first serious attempt at an application so i'm unsure if i'm making a lot more work for myself than needs to be done. Any critiquing  appreciated.

Comment: You question is well organized, but the title should be passing Js variable to php write? Is this your problem?

Comment: It looks as if your functions is expecting three arguments, you're only sending one. `function SCORE( cash, comp, num_months) {` and you're calling it with `SCORE( newCash );`

Comment: Have you opened your console to see if there are errors?

Comment: On top of what @JayBlanchard said, you should catch the returned value of `SCORE()` function like this: `var scoreTotal = SCORE(...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things that could potentially be wrong here.

Starting off, this line is unnecessarily complex:

```
var cash = parseFloat(JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($cash_flow); ?>'));
```

My assumption here is that `$cash_flow` is a number, since you're doing a parseInt on it. So you could just do this (Updated to use parseFloat as per Lawrence):

```
var cash = parseFloat('<?php echo $cash_flow; ?>');
```

Next, let's look at where you're changing the value

```
$('#cashFlowOutput').html(cash-=1000);
var newCash = $('#cashFlowOutput').html();
```

There's no need to use a dom element for this since you're just pulling the value right back out, you can do this instead:

```
var newCash = cash - 1000;
```

Then the final two lines:

```
SCORE( newCash );
$('#dvTestOut').html(scoreTotal);
```

Your `SCORE` function takes in 3 parameters, you're missing `comp` and `num_months`. Also, `scoreTotal` doesn't exist. I assume this is meant to be the result from the `SCORE` function, in which case you want it to look like this:

```
var comp = 10; // sample value
var num_months = 4; // sample value
var scoreTotal = SCORE( newCash, comp, num_months );
$('#dvTestOut').html(scoreTotal);
```

Comment: Your answer was perfect. But you missed a small detail here. He said he is trying to take inputs. And since it is a calculator and his variable clearly states that it refers to cash, so parseFloat() will work better then parseInt().

Comment: Appreciate the help Dr_Derp. During the value change, i do have the change displayed on the dom when the user updates it with + or - like so: http://imgur.com/a/9OL7U . Regarding the function part, referring to the image, i'd like the user to be able to click + or - on any of the inputs and run it through the SCORE() function. But if they update SCORE(cash) but not SCORE(num_months) i would like it to still process. Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: The imgur is helpful, it looks like there's some code missing then. Showing us what your initial HTML looks like would be useful. As far as the SCORE function, if you don't pass the num_months and the comp into the function, then it will def screw up the output. I'll whip up a jsfiddle that does a simple version of this so you can have something to go off of.

Comment: @DLzer this doens't do everything, but it's a good example of most of what you're trying to do, for a small part. I'll leave hooking up the rest as an exercise to you: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhc5nr69/

Comment: @Dr_Derp Pretty close to what i'm looking for, just missing a step of running it through a formula with multiple parameters. I added the basic html setup and also the repo to show the entire process.

Comment: The multiple parameters thing... Given the formula I see, they're going to have to come from somewhere. I don't know where you're getting them from in the initial score-wherever that is, you can probably just pass them into the call you make in the button handler.

Comment: Hmm.. Thinking about parameters coming from somewhere and seeing Lawrence's answer below. Would i be able to use a function like 
`$('#cashMinusBtn').click(function(){
    $('#cashFlowOutput').html(cash-=1000);
    var newCash = $('#cashFlowOutput').html();
    var comp = $('#compOut').html();
    var num_months = $('#monthsOut').html()
    dvSCORE( newCash, comp, num_months );
    $('#dvTestOut').html(dvScoreTotal);
  })`

Comment: Yeah, as long as `comp` and `num_months` are defined somewhere in your script that should work fine. I wouldn't use that code you just posted though, there are a number of issues with it that would cause bugs (outlined in both my own and Lawrence's answers)

Answer (score 1):

Your code in JQuery shown below has few glitches. Such as missing function arguments,closing bracket for the function, unassigned variable calls, etc.

```
$('#cashMinusBtn').click(function(){
$('#cashFlowOutput').html(cash-=1000);
SCORE( newCash );
$('#dvTestOut').html(scoreTotal);
```

It could be like this.

```
$('#cashMinusBtn').click(function(){
    num_months = 1; // temporary values
    comp = 1; // temporary values
    $('#dvTestOut').html(SCORE(parseFloat(<?php echo $cash_flow ?>) - 1000, comp, num_months));
});
```

function SCORE can also be modified if you do not want to pass the other 2 arguments as it was called in your code

```
SCORE( newCash );
```

You have to do as this

```
function SCORE(cash, comp = 1, num_months = 1) {
   var total1 = (cash - comp )/( num_months*12);
   var total2 = total1/2.5;
   var total3 = total2*100;
   var dvTotal = total3;
   return dvTotal;
}
```

where the default values for the arguments are 1, but if you want to change the values for every run then you have to use

```
SCORE(cash, comp, num_months)
```

But there is an exception here, if the user passes **num_months = 0**, then you will get a **division by zero error**. Hence you have to always check that, **the denominator will never be equal to 0**. If the denominator of a fraction is zero, the expression is not a legal fraction because it's overall value is undefined.

Comment: I added the github repo for more coverage of the complete code. I do actually have the 2 other arguments defined outside that current function. I was able to get it mostly working with `$('#cashMinusBtn').click(function(){
    $('#cashFlowOutput').html(cash-=1000);
    $('#dvScore').html(Math.ceil(dvSCORE($('#cashFlowOutput').html(), comp, monthly_payment)));
  })` I know it's not a very nicely structured function but it is working.